# How to adjust widths of the second row in Words table

Tags: apache-poi

I have a Word table with custom first row, but the following rows aren't adjusted. Please tell me why, and how to do the same widths of cells of the second row?

```
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();


    CTDocument1 doc = document.getDocument();
    CTBody body = doc.getBody();

    if (!body.isSetSectPr()) {
        body.addNewSectPr();
    }
    CTSectPr section = body.getSectPr();

    if(!section.isSetPgSz()) {
        section.addNewPgSz();
    }
    CTPageSz pageSize = section.getPgSz();
    pageSize.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(15840));
    pageSize.setH(BigInteger.valueOf(12240));

    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    CTSectPr ctSectPr = section ;//paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewSectPr();
    CTColumns ctColumns = ctSectPr.addNewCols();
    ctColumns.setNum(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
    XWPFRun test = paragraph.createRun();
    test.setFontSize(15);
    test.setBold(true);
    test.setFontFamily("Times New Roman");
    test.setText("Перечни документов, необходимые для применения и исполнения технических регламентов (форма № 21)");
    test.addBreak();

    XWPFTable supergroupTable = document.createTable();
    supergroupTable.setWidth(15200);
    //supergroupTable.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1*720));
    //supergroupTable.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(12*720));

    CTTblWidth tblWidth = supergroupTable.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();
    tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(400));
    supergroupTable.getRow(0).getCell(0).setText("№");
    //STTblWidth.DXA is used to specify width in twentieths of a point.
    tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);

    XWPFTableRow supegroupRow = supergroupTable.getRow(0);
    XWPFTableCell supergroupCell = supegroupRow.createCell();
    tblWidth = supergroupTable.getRow(0).getCell(1).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();
    tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1700));
    tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
    supergroupCell.setText("Обозначение технического регламента");

    supergroupCell = supegroupRow.createCell();
    tblWidth = supergroupTable.getRow(0).getCell(2).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();
    tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1700));
    tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
    supergroupCell.setText("Наименование на русском языке ");

    supergroupCell = supegroupRow.createCell();
    tblWidth = supergroupTable.getRow(0).getCell(3).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();
    tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(880));
    tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
    supergroupCell.setText("Статус");

    supergroupCell = supegroupRow.createCell();
    tblWidth = supergroupTable.getRow(0).getCell(4).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();
    tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1700));
    tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
    supergroupCell.setText("Обозначение документа");

    supergroupCell = supegroupRow.createCell();
    tblWidth = supergroupTable.getRow(0).getCell(5).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();
    tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1700));
    tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
    supergroupCell.setText("Наименование на русском языке");

    supergroupCell = supegroupRow.createCell();
    tblWidth = supergroupTable.getRow(0).getCell(6).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();
    tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(880));
    tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
    supergroupCell.setText("Статус");

    supegroupRow = supergroupTable.createRow();
    supergroupCell = supegroupRow.getCell(0);
    supergroupCell.setText("cell 1");
    supergroupCell = supegroupRow.getCell(1);
    supergroupCell.setText("cell 2");
    supergroupCell = supegroupRow.getCell(2);
    supergroupCell.setText("cell 3");
    supergroupCell = supegroupRow.getCell(3);
    supergroupCell.setText("cell 4");
    supergroupCell = supegroupRow.getCell(4);
    supergroupCell.setText("cell 5");
    supergroupCell = supegroupRow.getCell(5);
    supergroupCell.setText("cell 6");
    supergroupCell = supegroupRow.getCell(6);
    supergroupCell.setText("cell 7");
```

When I trying to set width of the second row in the same manner that it is set up for the first row the document come to mess and I can't do it the same manner.

[image: The resulting document]

Comment: What `apache poi` version are you using? Current versions provide `setWidth` methods on high level, so the low level `CT...` classes are not needed. Using the low level `CT...` classes one needs special knowledge of the `XML`which needs to be created, else one creates wrong `XML` very fast.

Comment: <dependency.poi.version>3.10.1-20151016-alfresco-patched</dependency.poi.version>

Comment: Sorry `apache poi 3.10` is too old. I will not bothering myself with such ancient software. Nobody should use such old software. Current version is `apache poi  5.0.0`.

Comment: ok, I will update

Comment: I have upgraded to version 4.0.1

Comment: The setWidth method remains the second row the same

Answer (score 1):

Current versions of `apache poi` provide `setWidth` methods on high level, so the low level `CT...` classes are not needed. Using the low level `CT...` classes one needs special knowledge of the exact `XML` which needs to be created, else one creates wrong `XML` very fast. This seems to be the case in your case.

Using current `apache poi 5.0.0` creating a table as yours is as simple as this:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPageSz;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STPageOrientation;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordTableCellWidths {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  //page settings are not provided high level on apache poi until now.
  CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
  CTPageSz pageSz = sectPr.addNewPgSz();
  pageSz.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(15840)); //15840 Twips = 15840/20 = 792 pt = 792/72 = 11"
  pageSz.setH(BigInteger.valueOf(12240)); //12240 Twips = 12240/20 = 612 pt = 612/72 = 8.5"
  pageSz.setOrient(STPageOrientation.LANDSCAPE);

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Header line...");

  //create table having first row having 7 columns
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(1, 7);

  table.setWidth("100%");

  //set cell width and content for first row
  table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setText("Nr.");
  table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setWidth("400");
  table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setText("Loremipsumsemitdolor dolorsemitloremipsum semitdolor");
  table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setWidth("1700");
  table.getRow(0).getCell(2).setText("Lorem ipsum semit dolor dolor semit lorem");
  table.getRow(0).getCell(2).setWidth("1700");
  table.getRow(0).getCell(3).setText("Lorem ipsum");
  table.getRow(0).getCell(3).setWidth("880");
  table.getRow(0).getCell(4).setText("Lorem ipsum semit dolor dolor semit lorem");
  table.getRow(0).getCell(4).setWidth("1700");
  table.getRow(0).getCell(5).setText("Lorem ipsum semit dolor dolor semit lorem");
  table.getRow(0).getCell(5).setWidth("1700");
  table.getRow(0).getCell(6).setText("Lorem ipsum");
  table.getRow(0).getCell(6).setWidth("880");

  //create further row
  XWPFTableRow row = table.createRow();
  row.getCell(0).setText("cell 1");
  row.getCell(0).setWidth("400");
  row.getCell(1).setText("cell 2");
  row.getCell(1).setWidth("1700");
  row.getCell(2).setText("cell 3");
  row.getCell(2).setWidth("1700");
  row.getCell(3).setText("cell 4");
  row.getCell(3).setWidth("880");
  row.getCell(4).setText("cell 5");
  row.getCell(4).setWidth("1700");
  row.getCell(5).setText("cell 6");
  row.getCell(5).setWidth("1700");
  row.getCell(6).setText("cell 7");
  row.getCell(6).setWidth("880");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordTableCellWidths.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Only page settings are not provided high level on apache poi until now. So to set page settings using the low level `CT...` classes is necessary.

For usage in `Microsoft Word` in general you set cell widths for cells in first row only. Further rows are using those cell widths too except if there are merged cells used.

For usage in `Libreoffice` or `OpenOffice` `Writer` width of all cells in all rows needs to be set.

Comment: cannot access org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPageSz
[ERROR]   class file for org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPageSz not found
Alfresco upgraded to 6.2 (Apache POI 4.0.1) , could you help me with that?

Comment: You need `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` in class path.